# why wont my set interval work in react native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setinterval

so im working on making a timer count down from some given amount of time which is determined by a slider.
then one can click a start button starting at the slider's value, and begin the count down.
(as it is though, im just working with set values, which I will then somehow link up this slider)

ive been working around this setinterval() func just to see if I can make it count down from 60. but after a few seconds it starts to count radically. i think it has to do with my lack of understanding of state and the way it renders the state repeatedly, or something.

---just learning so bear with the irationality of this code, criticism is apprecieated!---

```
export const Timer = ({navigation}) => {

    const [minutes, setMin] = useState(30);
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(60);

    let value = 30;

    const handleSliderChange = (value) => {
        setMin(value)
    }
    function minusSecond() { 
        setSeconds(seconds- 1)
    }


    return(
        <View style={styles.Timer}>
            <Text style={styles.Txt2}>M I N U T E S</Text>
            <View style={styles.Slider}>
                <Slider
                  style={{width: 300, height:40}}
                  minimumValue={5}
                  maximumValue={120}
                  value={value}
                  step={5}
                  thumbTintColor='white'
                  minimumTrackTintColor="#FFFFFF"
                  maximumTrackTintColor="#000000"
                  onValueChange={handleSliderChange}
                />  
            </View>

            <View>
                <Text style={styles.Time}>
                    {minutes}:{seconds}
                </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.Start}>
                <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.buttonStyle} title="Start" onPress={setInterval(setSeconds, 1000)}}>
                    <Text style={styles.ButtonTxt}>START</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.buttonStyle } title="Home Page">
                    <Text style={styles.ButtonTxt}>STOP</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: You need to use `useEffect()` for it and cleari when unmount also Go through lots of related posts from search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breactjs%5DsetInterval+hooks

Comment: You're calling setSeconds with undefined in the interval, and you never clear it either. Also mutation outside of useEffect is a no-no.

Comment: `onPress={setInterval(setSeconds, 1000)}` is wrong - you want `onPress={() => setInterval(setSeconds, 1000)}`, otherwise the `setInterval` gets called every time the component is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your countdown timer logic should look something like this:

```
const [countDown, setCountDown] = React.useState(60);
const [startTimer, setTimer] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (startTimer) {
        setCountDown(countDown > 0 ? countDown - 1 : 0);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, [countDown, startTimer]);

  const resetCountDown = () => {
    setCountDown(60);
  };
```

Check out the example project below for a live demo.

https://snack.expo.io/@bapeter01/countdown-example